# How do I reach the extra switches in the Waterway puzzle?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

I have solved the basic waterway puzzle where you press the 4 switches and get to the end and then press the 5th switch which opens the door for the Riku battle. Isn't there more to the maze? If you look closely you can see there are 2 more switches that I can't seem to get to.

```
-------------------
|     L     \   * |
|B(X) L     \     |
|     L     \     |
\\\\\\\-----\\\\\\\
|     \  S2 \     |
|S4   \     \     |
|     \     \     |
------\\\\\\\\\\\\\
|     \     |     |
|S1   \     |   S3|
|     \     |     |
nnnnnn\\\\\\\\\\\\\
|     n     ?     |
|     n     ?   * |
|E    n     ?     |
-------------------
```

---- or |||| is unmoveable
 n is no wall
 L is a low wall that you can jump over
 s# is a switch
 * is a switch you can see but cant get to
 X is an exit
 E is an entry

does anyone have any clue how to get to the switches? I've done google searches but I haven't found one for full maze completion, just the first part. Here is one theory I have:

```
-------------------
|     L     L   * |
|B    L     L     |
|     L     L     |
nnnnnnn-----+------
|     n  S2 |     |
|S4   n     |     |
|     n     |     |
-------------------
|     |     |     |
|S1   |     |   S3|
|     |     |     |
nnnnnn-------------
|     n     ?     |
|     n     ?   * |
|     n     ?     |
-------------------
```

If you get the maze to look like this, then if you could get in from the exit or some other point towards the end of the maze, you would have access to the switch. Just a thought though. Ive looked all throughout the entire world and I am unable to find another entry point to this maze. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you've hit the 4 buttons you've mentioned, and battled Riku, than there isn't any more buttons you need to hit in the dungeon. I can't specifically remember the buttons you are referring to, but in looking online, it seems you weren't the [only](http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/kh-hollow-bastion-dungeon-buttons-and-treasure.194369727/) [one](http://forums.khinsider.com/kingdom-hearts-series/17934-possibly-hardest-puzzle-all-kingdom-hearts.html) to notice them. But, they don't seem to be reachable, and they don't unlock anything anyway, so you can just forget about them. They are decoration.

Don't forget to get the other items in there though (notably a Blue Trinity and I believe 3 chests).

Comment: I kind of feel like they're not for decoration, you can lock onto them which means you can probably interact with them. Are you sure about this?

Comment: @John I honestly don't have my copy to test, but the only references to it have been people who are unable to get there. The first link is from someone who has beat the game a few times, so I'm fairly sure. When I get my copy back, I'll test this out though.

Comment: +1 Ok thank you, I've been working on it forever and i feel like why would they take the time to put those switches in there if they didn't lead to something? just a thought.

Comment: @John are you sure you can lock on to them? I am unable to do so in my game.

Comment: yes i was able to

Comment: @John Odd. Well I am unable to and there is no way to get access to either of the two in question. I'm not sure how you could lock on to them, but likely it may just be a bug in your version of the game (especially if you have an early version or something).

Answer (score 0):

There is a lowered bubble and you freeze that to get a chest with dark matter inside but any other bubbles aren't for anything besides going under the water in waterway just look for alow bubble and freeze that and you can get up top.

Answer (score 0):

Found the lift stop area! As soon as you get to the lift stop from the castle entrance, there's a crystal to the right that can either go to lower area or upper area. The crystal to the left toggles which way the lift will go. Take it to the lower area to reach the waterway with two platforms. One of these platforms is blocking the way to the section of the maze which was unreachable, just behind the rotating walls. The only problem is the platform goes up instead of down. There is still no way to reach it.

Answer (score -1):

To answer this indefinitely there is some where in the lift stop a switch that takes you down into the waterway. Using this lift stop you'll be able to reach the other switches in question.